# Can't run debug mode in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-errors

I get the following message whenever I set a break point and run debug mode:

[image: Error Message]

Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Edit: I switched the Debugger Type from auto to mixed and now the program runs through all breakpoints without stopping.
This is the Debug Output:

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Julian\Desktop\Project2\Debug\Project2.exe', Symbol format not supported.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

'Project2.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file.

The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x46f4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3650) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x3860) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[18976] Project2.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Can you post your source code here ?

Comment: Looks like you need to set the correct debug engines to use.  Its an option somewhere (I don't recall where, maybe debug properties for your project).  Looks like you need to be sure that "native" is one of the selected engines.

Comment: @SaCh It happens with any code, even just a cout >> "Hello World"; console application.

I switched the Debug mode from auto to mixed and now the console application executes normally, running through all breakpoints without stopping.

I added the Debug output to the original post.